# Frama-C unbound module Z build error

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

Using Ubuntu 14.04, I downloaded the Neon Frama-C distribution, and installed the required tools: labgtk, sourceview, etc.  I configured Frama-C no problem, but on building got:

```
File "external/unz.ml", line 39, characters 10-19:
Error: Unbound module Z
make: *** [external/unz.cmo] Error 2
```

The problem is

```
 let n = Z.of_bits str in
```

where Z denotes a module that is not imported (I guess).  I do not know what Z is supposed to refer to so I have no way of trying to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you installed the `zarith` library (`libzarith-ocaml-dev` under Ubuntu)? Frama-C can use two libraries for arbitrary precision integers: either `Bignum`, which is included in OCaml distribution (although I wouldn't be surprised that Debian/Ubuntu did manage to make it a separate package ), or `Zarith`, a newer, more efficient implementation. `unz.ml` is part of the code that binds
`Zarith` to Frama-C, thus if you don't have `Zarith`installed, you will have some issues compiling it.

Normally, `./configure` should take care of choosing the appropriate library. You can check what it has found in `config.log`. A possible issue is that you have package `libzarith-ocaml` installed but not `libzarith-ocaml-dev`. In this case, the library itself is installed (and presumably detected by `./configure`), but not the headers needed to compile the code against it.

Comment: The advantages of the Zarith library over Bignum are revealed in these blog posts: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/10/09/Zarith and http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/10/17/Features-in-Nitrogen-1

Comment: It was exactly that libzarith-ocaml was installed and not libzarith-ocaml-dev